# Write to Sheet with Google Sheets API

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I want write data to my sheet:

```
$spreadsheetId = 'xxx';
$range = 'Test!A1:D5';

$values = [
  'range' => "A1",
  'majorDimension' => 'DIMENSION_UNSPECIFIED',
  'values' => [
    ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
    ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
    ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
    ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
  ],
];

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array(
  'values' => $values
));
$params = array(
  'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
);
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
```

But in log i see:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"range\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"major_dimension\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"range\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"major_dimension\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I will be grateful for the example code that works for you :)

In the examples there is not enough information( https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range)

Comment: have you resolved this?

Comment: Only with [Writing multiple ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_multiple_ranges). Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Don't forget to include the sheet name

```
 "range": "Sheet1!A1:D5"
```

Check the [Basic Writing guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing) for more samples.

Comment: The same result :-(

Comment: Im only familiar with JS implementation. But the official PHP implementation is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range) for Writing on cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$spreadsheetId = 'xxx';
$range = 'Test!A1:D5';

$values = [
    ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
    ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
    ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
    ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
];

$updateBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'range' => $range,
    'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
    'values' => $values,
]);

$valueInputOption = 'USER_ENTERED'; // Or RAW       

$params = [
  'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption
];

$result = $this->sheetsService->spreadsheets_values->update(
    $spreadsheetID,
    $updateRange,
    $updateBody,
    $params
);
```

Comment: must set $updateRange = $range = 'Test!A1:D5' to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

Not the case here, but I have solved a similar issue by removing `NULL` values from the items inside of the `values` array.

Google's PHP library seems to have a hard time parsing these values and ends up generating an invalid JSON payload.